# Accept best answer, or used answer with used method?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Regarding this question of mine:
[Why is my onchange function called twice when using .focus()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166086/why-is-my-onchange-function-called-twice-when-using-focus)

There are several answers and one provides a solution that looks valid. Now I also did some testing and came up with a quick fix myself that, as it turns out, would be implemented anyway in a later stage<sup>1</sup>.

So now I have two answers. The one that is best for my situation (my own answer) and one that I feel is a better 'overall' solution.

Which would be the best to accept?

<sup>1: My hack was to remove an onclick listener. This is sortof a hack to stop a bug where it gets called twice when it shouldn't, but as I need it to fire only once anyway, I would have removed it in any case later. If that makes sense :)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of marking an answer should primarily to make it a "sticky" to stay on top. This is to highlight that you (the asker) felt it most appropriate for his/her particular question/problem.  So I would accept my own answer.

However, you can also edit your final solution into the answer that got you closest so that

1. The community still get to see the "best" solution prominently
2. The person who answered your question gets the reputation s/he deserves

Etiquette suggests putting a `<hr>` and `###EDIT` between the answer and your new information.

Comment: That last seems to be a nice solution. I think the thing here is that there is a difference between the actual problem (which my answer was the solution for) and the question (which was more simplified, and which the other users answer was the best for).

Comment: Nanne - your answer should preferably address the question posed, not some phantom question (even if IRL) which has ghost information never revealed in SO - it wouldn't make sense to anyone else otherwise.

Comment: I agree, although "phantom question" implies a little bigger difference then there actually is, so -as always- it might be less black/white