# Should I accept the answer I like most, or the one that is most useful for others?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, best-practices

I've asked a question, which has a number of answers. One of them has 16 upvotes, big answer, very complete, and is probably going to be the most useful for other visitors in the future. On the other hand, there is another answer, 0 upvotes, just one little paragraph that provides me with exactly what I need.

Should I accept the small answer that perfectly solves *my* problem, or should I accept the broader answer, and that is going to benefit the greatest number of future visitors with similar problems?

Comment: related: [Accept best answer, or used answer with used method?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81473/262755)

Answer (score 4):

It is entirely up to you which answer you choose to accept.  It does not necessarily have to be the highest voted answer.

In short, select the answer that you feel best answers your question. Chances are, that the one you select will also assist others, and the highly voted answer will also still be there for future viewers.

*and remember, you can always change your mind which answer you accept*